# Talkback not reading data table headers in Android Lollipop

Tags: cordova, android-5.0-lollipop, talkback

when I upgraded to Android 5.x it looks like Talkback will no longer read the data table headers in hybrid app. Anybody know if this is broken?

I am using Cordova and jQuery Mobile to create my app and below is the code that I am using:

```
<div id="home" data-role="page" data-title="Home">
        <div data-role="content">
            <div date-role="header">
                <h1>Data Table 1</h1>
            </div>
            <div role="main" class="ui-content">
                <table  data-role="table" id="my-table" data-mode="reflow">
                   <tr>
                       <th id="c1">Service Branch</th>
                       <th id="c2">Percentage of Women</th>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                       <th id="r1">Army</th>
                       <td headers="r6 c2">13.4%</td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                       <th id="r2">Navy</th>
                       <td headers="r2 c2">15.9%</td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                       <th id="r3">Marine Corps</th>
                       <td headers="r3 c2">6.6%</td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                       <th id="r4">Air Force</th>
                       <td headers="r4 c2">19.2%</td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                       <th id="r5">Coast Guard</th>
                       <td headers="r5 c2">13.4%</td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                       <th id="r6">National Guard & Reserves</th>
                       <td headers="r6 c2">17.9%</td>
                   </tr>
               </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the pattern suggested by a11y project? They are using the "scope" attribute instead of "headers".

```
<table>
  <caption>Star Wars Trilogy Data</caption>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Title</th>
      <th scope="col">Director</th>
      <th scope="col">Release Date</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">Star Wars: Episode IV - A New Hope</th>
      <td>George Lucas</td>
      <td>May 25th, 1977</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">Star Wars: Episode V - The Empire Strikes Back</th>
      <td>Irvin Kershner</td>
      <td>May 21st, 1980</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">Star Wars: Episode VI - Return of the Jedi</th>
      <td>Richard Marquand</td>
      <td>May 25th, 1983</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

http://codepen.io/svinkle/pen/zmlEi

Comment: Shouldn't the first row be within `thead` tag?

Comment: According to WebAIM, it doesn't make a difference if its in a thead. http://webaim.org/techniques/tables/data#other